# GroupBy bool and Select values for new list

Tags: c#, linq, livecharts

I am trying to get into more complex Linq queries and right away catch a point I am feeling stuck. I have a following list in DB:

```
ID            ELAPSED TIME           APPISRUNNING
1               12                        TRUE
2               54                        TRUE
3               32                        FALSE
```

Where ELAPSED TIME is TimeSpan and APPISRUNNING is a bool.

I would like to build a chart based on these values (https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/LiveCharts2). Chart build fine with this:

```
 Title = "Analytics";
  this.ActivityChartSeries = new ISeries[]
  {
    new PieSeries<double> { Values = new double[] { 2 }},
    new PieSeries<double> { Values = new double[] { 2 }},
    new PieSeries<double> { Values = new double[] { 2 }},
    new PieSeries<double> { Values = new double[] { 2 }},
    new PieSeries<double> { Values = new double[] { 2 }},
  };
```

Now I somehow need to first GroupBy bool and then select a new List? I have tried following:

```
  IEnumerable<DataRecord> dataRecords = await this.DataStore.GetItemsAsync();

  this.ActivityChartSeries = dataRecords
    .GroupBy(g => g.AppIsRunning)
    .Select(m => new
    { // BELOW IS TOTALLY UNCLEAR FOR ME
      Values = m.Select(r => r.EngineElapsed.Ticks),
      Name = m.Select(r => r.Name),
    })
    .Select(x =>
    new PieSeries<double>
    {
      Values = new List<double> { x.Values.FirstOrDefault() },
      Name = x.Name.FirstOrDefault(),
    });
```

Type of assigned variable:

```
public IEnumerable<ISeries> ActivityChartSeries
```

This part is totally unclear for me:

```
      Values = m.Select(r => r.EngineElapsed.Ticks),
      Name = m.Select(r => r.Name),
```

How after GroupBy I can create two types of data? Basically I need

1. "Application Running" and "Values"
2. "Application is not Running" and "Values"

---

EDIT:

Code provided by Somar Zein compiles fine:

```
var results = activityChartSeries
            .GroupBy(a=> a.AppIsRunning)
            .Select(item=> new PieSeries<double>{
                        Name = item.Key ? "Application is Running" : "Application is not Running",
                        Values = item.Select(x=> Convert.ToDouble(x.ElapsedTime.Ticks)).ToList()
        });
```

However as a result I am getting something like this, why it is reloading in a loop?

Here is result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4y1z.gif)

---

**EDIT2:**

So I have created an example for testing purposes:

Class:

```
  public class DataModel
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan ElapsedTime { get; set; }
    public bool AppIsRunning { get; set; }
  }
```

Code:

```
  List<DataModel> records = new List<DataModel>();

  records.Add(new DataModel { Id = 1, ElapsedTime = new TimeSpan(1, 20, 30), AppIsRunning = true });
  records.Add(new DataModel { Id = 2, ElapsedTime = new TimeSpan(1, 20, 30), AppIsRunning = true });
  records.Add(new DataModel { Id = 3, ElapsedTime = new TimeSpan(1, 20, 30), AppIsRunning = true });
  records.Add(new DataModel { Id = 4, ElapsedTime = new TimeSpan(1, 20, 30), AppIsRunning = true });
  records.Add(new DataModel { Id = 5, ElapsedTime = new TimeSpan(1, 20, 30), AppIsRunning = true });

  this.ActivityChartSeries = records
    .GroupBy(g => g.AppIsRunning)
    .Select(item => new PieSeries<double>
    {
      Name = item.Key ? "Running" : "Not Running",
      Values = new double[] { 2, 4 },
    });
```

I get the same reloading effect, even thou originally provided Example from LiveCharts work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try doing something like following:

```
var results = activityChartSeries
            .GroupBy(a=> a.AppIsRunning)
            .Select(item=> new PieSeries<double>{
                        Name = item.Key ? "Application is Running" : "Application is not Running",
                        Values = item.Select(x=> Convert.ToDouble(x.ElapsedTime.Ticks)).ToList()
        });
```

hope that could be helpful!

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could you please check what might be the problem of looping and reloading chart? I don't understand at all... I have edited my question and added an screen recording of result

Comment: I have provided original Chart API example. I am thinking API is used wrong that causing such a behaviour?

Comment: I couldn't tell what is really causing the problem, could you please more info? how do you bind the results to the chart?

Comment: Does the return type of the query matches the accepted data-type source of the charts? What i saw wrong in the GIF is that the PieChart has 50% unknown data? is it really so, or the GIF does not give the full picture?

Comment: I have added EDIT 2. Of course it is maybe a bit off topic, but I basically wanted to get this chart showing some data in a nice way

Comment: if you still see the same result with static data like the one you provided in Edit2 then there is something wrong else where. What is the type of your project?

Comment: I think I can ask new question realted especially to Livecharts